# How can I apply different custom caption styles to different listings?

Tags: listings, captions

In the MWE below, is it possible to define different caption formats for the two listings? In the example the first listing should use a blue caption background (like it is now) while the second should be red. However, in general I want to be able to have completely different captions on different listings, for example some listings will have captions above while some will have captions below. It seems like `captionsetup` is a global option, and I can find no documentation on how to apply it only to a single or group of listings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{calc} 
\lstdefinestyle{outline}{
         basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
         numberstyle=\tiny,
         numbersep=5pt,
         tabsize=2,
         extendedchars=true,
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},
         frame=b,
         stringstyle=\color{green!40!black}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,
         showtabs=false,
         numbers=left,
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         showstringspaces=false,
         backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{200,200,200},
         belowcaptionskip=-1pt
}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[RGB]{60,100,180}{\parbox{\textwidth - 2 \fboxsep}{\hspace{14pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=outline,caption=Blue]
This should have blue caption.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=outline,caption=Red]
This should have red caption.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new tcolorbox with listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{outline}{
         basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
         numberstyle=\tiny,
         numbersep=5pt,
         tabsize=2,
         extendedchars=true,
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},
         stringstyle=\color{green!40!black}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,
         showtabs=false,
         numbers=left,
         showstringspaces=false,
}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{60,100,180}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{mylist}[2][]{%
    title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
    colback=lightgray,
    colframe=myblue,
    fonttitle={\footnotesize\bfseries},
    sharp corners,
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    left=17pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    toptitle=4pt,
    bottomtitle=4pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={style=outline},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}{Blue and above}
This should have blue caption.
\end{mylist}

\begin{mylist}[%
    flip title={sharp corners},
    colbacktitle=red
    ]{Red and below}
This should have red caption.
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]